# How to use regex to match this html tag?

Tags: php, regex

I can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong...

I'm trying to find matches of

```
<cite>stuffhere</cite>
```

Is this right?

```
preg_match_all('<cite>(.*?)</cite>/ms', $str, $matches)
```

Comment: '<cite>(.*?)<\/cite>/ms'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your confusion is not your fault; PHP is notoriously weird in this area.

In most programming languages, you create a regex object one of two ways.  If the language supports regexes as a first-class language element, you can use a regex literal:

```
var re = /<b>"\w+"<\/b>/;  // JavaScript
```

Here, the forward-slash (`/`) is the *regex delimiter*; if you want to match a literal `/`, you have to escape it with a backslash: `\/`.

In other languages, you have to write the regex in the form of a string literal, which you then pass to a constructor or a factory method:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("<b>\"\\w+\"</b>");  // Java
```

The forward-slash doesn't need to be escaped, but both the double-quote (`"`) and backslash (`\`) do, because of their special meanings in string literals.

But PHP is unique: it doesn't support regex literals, so you have to write the regex as a string, but the string has to *look* like a regex literal!  That is, it has to have string delimiters (quotes) **and** regex delimiters.  For example:

```
$re = '/<b>"\w+"<\/b>/';
```

It isn't all bad; as you can see, you can use PHP's single-quoted strings instead of double-quoted, so you don't have to escape all backslashes and double-quotes.  You can also choose different regex delimiters, so you don't have to escape (for example) literal forward-slashes in your regex:

```
$re = '~<cite>(.*?)</cite>~s'
```

The modifiers ('s' for single-line, 'i' for ignore-case, etc.) go after the trailing regex delimiter, as in Perl or JavaScript.  Almost any ASCII punctuation character can be used as a regex delimiter; `~` and `#` are popular choices.

Answer (score 3):

escape the `/`

```
preg_match_all('/<cite>(.*?)<\/cite>/ms', $str, $matches);
```

Comment: ...and add the missing `/` at the beginning (probably a typo in the question).

Answer (score 1):

You should use an HTML Parser to parse html, or you will end up with unexpected errors. However, this is what your regex should be:

```
'#<cite>(.*?)</cite>#s'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
preg_match_all('/<cite>(.*?)<\/cite>/ms', $str, $matches);
```